# SQL Decode Null Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query.  When `type_id is null` I want it to be grouped by the name "unknown".
How can I do it.
I know there is a decode function but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
select type_id,
       name
  from test_table
 group by decode(type_id,'Unknown'),
          name;
```

how can I do it?

Comment: DECODE is decode(column, potentialvalue, result, 2ndpotentialvalue, result, ...NpotentialValue, result, elsevalue) Case statements are a bit easier to read so are preferred by some.  Just FYI - a GREAT resource for quick definitions of functions is TechOnTheNet.  http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php You can easily google "Oracle decode" and it takes you right to the above linked page.  Saves posting and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select decode(type_id, null, 'Unknown', type_id), name, count(*)
from
(
    select 'asdf' type_id, 'name1' name from dual union all
    select 'asdf' type_id, 'name2' name from dual union all
    select null type_id,   'name3' name from dual
) test_table
group by type_id,name;
```

I agree with @sql_mommy that `CASE` would probably look better.  But I disagree about using TechOnTheNet as your primary source of information.  You are usually better off with the official documentation, and the [page for DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions049.htm#SQLRF00631) is a good example of why.

`DECODE` has some strange behavior: "In a DECODE function, Oracle considers two nulls to be equivalent."  That behavior is not mentioned in the TechOnTheNet article.

Comment: +1 for promoting the Oracle documentation over TechOnTheNet. TOTN can make understanding certain features easier but they can gloss over important information at times.

Answer (score 11):

For null, we have the NVL function. It can be used as follows

```
select nvl(type_id,'Unknown'),name from test_table group by
type_id,name;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use either the `NVL` function or `COALESCE`:

```
select NVL(type_id, 'Unknown') AS type_id,
       name
  from test_table
 group by NVL(type_id, 'Unknown'),
          name;
```

Or

```
select COALESCE(type_id, 'Unknown') AS type_id,
       name
  from test_table
 group by COALESCE(type_id, 'Unknown'),
          name;
```

`COALESCE` is more efficient than `NVL` as it only evaluates the second argument if the first is NULL whereas `NVL` evaluates both arguments every time.

Hope it helps...